# GWT: 100 LOC Rule of Thumb?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I've read several GWT developer blogs that mentioned some "rule of thumb" whereby if your resultant JavaScript will be 100 lines of code or greater, it is better to just write the JavaScript yourself (instead of generating it through GWT).

My question is: how can you tell how many LOC GWT will produce? This seems like a difficult rule of thumb to follow, and one that requires writing 2 sets of code (first writing the GWT, and then re-writing it in JavaScript)!?!?

Have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: Can you cite where you saw this rule of thumb? I can't imagine a GWT developer suggesting that you only use GWT for _short_ scripts (though I could easily see it the other way around). GWT's optimizing compiler does its best work when it has lots of code to go over and clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of GWT is to save us from having to write JavaScript and using Vaadin (a java Web applications framework built on top of GWT)  I created a number of UI controls I wouldn't even know how to do in JavaScript. 
The concern you do need to keep in mind is performance. I wrote a form that took over 20 seconds to render in IE8. It doesn't matter how many LOC to your users, no one will wait so long for a page to appear.

Comment: Thanks @Thorn (+1), but it is obvious that the end objective is performance, thats why this "rule of thumb" exists in the first place. My question is about *applying* the rule of thumb to achieve better performance.

Comment: Under most circumstances, I would expect a short script to run quickly.  I just don't think this rule is practical to apply. There are scripts GWT generated for me that were much longer than 100 lines and they ran fine,  even in slow IE8. Don't tweak performance unless you need to.